React UseContext not updating state
I am attempting to update state using a context provider. I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.
The state simply doesn't update. If anyone could point me in the right direction or suggest resources I can consult, I would be eternally grateful.
My code is below:
// App.tsx
import "./styles.css";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";
import { AuthProvider } from "./AuthContext";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <MyComponent />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}



//MyComponent.tsx
import "./styles.css";
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext";

export default function MyComponent() {
  const { user, setUser } = useAuth();
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello {user.name} How are you today?</h1>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setUser({ name: "Registered User" });
        }}
      >
        Update User
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}


// AuthContext.tsx
import { createContext, useContext, useState, ReactNode } from "react";

// Define an interface for the context value
interface AuthContextType {
  user: any;
  setUser: (authUser: any) => void;
}

// Create the context with a default value
let defaultAuthContext: AuthContextType = {
  user: { name: "Guest" },
  setUser: (authUser: any) => {},
};

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(defaultAuthContext);

interface AuthProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = (): AuthContextType => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider");
  }
  return context;
};

I have created a codesandbox showing the issue I have encountered https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/4vw2yq
Update (What I have tried):
I moved the useAuth call into its own child component, however the behavior is still the same.

Hi Mick, did you try to wrap your application with AuthProvider AND then call the state inside another component ?
I guess useAuth is being called outside of the AuthProvider context.
Try this :
const MyComponent= () => {
  const { user, setUser } = useAuth();

  return (
...
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setUser({ name: "Registered User" });
        }}
      >
...
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
        <MyComponent />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}


Hi @nboyet I took your suggestion, however something is sadly still amiss. I have updated my post.

In AuthContext.tsx, line 23, change to const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: "Guest" });

const [user, setUser] = useState<any>({ name: "Guest" });

Explanation:
Without proper initialisation of the user state, the user object may be undefined, causing issues when trying to access user.name. By initialising the state with a default value ({ name: "Guest" }), the application behaves as expected, and the state updates correctly when setUser is called.
